# Why when I use a variable in the command does it stop working? || Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

good morning, I am a newbie in the world of scripts and I have this problem and I don't know why it happens to me and why I have it wrong, thanks in advance.

For example, I have this command that searches for users with X less letters:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | awk 'length($1) <= 4'
```

It works correctly but when I substitute a 4 for a variable with the same value it doesn't do it well:

```
number=4
echo -e $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | awk 'length($1) <= $number')
```

The same error happens to me here too, when I search for users who have an old password

```
awk -F: '{if($3<=18388)print$1}' < /etc/shadow
```

Works, but when I use the variable it stops working

```
variable=18388
awk -F: '{if($3<=$variable)print$1}' < /etc/shadow
```

Comment: Just use full awk: `awk -F: -v number=4 'length($1) <= number { print $1 }' /etc/passwd`. `cut` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes:

```
echo -e $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | awk "length(\$1) <= $number")
```

In single quotes, variables are not interpreted.

Updated: Here is an illustrative example:

```
> X=1; echo '$X'; echo "$X"
$X
1
```

Update 2: as rightfully pointed out in the comment, when using double quotes one need to make sure that the variables that are meant for `awk` to interpret are escaped, so they are not interpreted during script evaluation. Command updated above.

Comment: But `$1` might get interpreted, too.

Comment: ah, good point, you'll need to escape that. Let me update the question.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `awk's` ability to import variables via the `-v` option, eg:

```
number=4
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | awk -v num="${number}" 'length($1) <= num'
```

Though if the first field from `/etc/passwd` contains white space, and you want to consider the length of the entire field, you should replace `$1` with `$0`, eg:

```
number=4
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | awk -v num="${number}" 'length($0) <= num'
```

Even better, eliminate `cut` and the subprocess (due to the pipe) and use `awk` for the entire operation by designating the input field separator as a colon:

```
number=4
awk -F':' -v num="${number}" 'length($1) <= num { print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this task could be done using only a single GNU `sed` one-liner:

```
num=4
sed -E "s/:.*//; /..{$num}/d" /etc/passwd
```

Another one-liner, using only `grep` would be

```
grep -Po "^[^:]{1,$num}(?=:)" /etc/passwd
```

but this requires a grep supporting perl regular expressions, for the lookahead construct `(?=...)`.